# How can I optimize this mysql query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I would like to ask, how can I optimize this query:

```
select
    h.jmeno hrac,
    n1.url hrac_url,
    t.nazev tym,
    n2.url tym_url,
    ss.pocet_zapasu zapasy,
    ss.pocet_minut minuty,
    s.celkem_golu goly,
    s.zk,
    s.ck
from
    hraci h
left join
    (
        select
            hrac_id,
            tym_id,
            count(minut_celkem) pocet_zapasu,
            sum(minut_celkem)  pocet_minut
        from
            statistiky_stridani ss
        join 
            zapasy z
                on z.id = ss.zapas_id
        join
            souteze s
                on s.id = z.soutez_id
        join
            souteze_nazev sn
                on sn.id = s.soutez_id
        where
            s.rocnik_id = 2
        group by
            hrac_id
    ) ss on ss.hrac_id = h.id
left join
    (
        select
            hrac_id,
            tym_id,
            sum(typ_id = 1 or typ_id = 3) as celkem_golu,
            sum(typ_id = 4) as zk,
            sum(typ_id = 5) as ck
        from
            statistiky st
        join 
            zapasy z
                on z.id = st.zapas_id
        join
            souteze s
                on s.id = z.soutez_id
        join
            souteze_nazev sn
                on sn.id = s.soutez_id
        where
            s.rocnik_id = 2
        group by
            hrac_id
    ) s on s.hrac_id = h.id
join
    navigace n1
        on n1.id = h.nav_id
join
    tymy t
        on t.id = ss.tym_id
join
    navigace n2
        on n2.id = t.nav_id
order by
    s.celkem_golu desc
limit 
    10
```

Because query takes about 1,5 - 2 seconds. For example, table statistiky_stridani has about 500 000 rows and statistiky about 250 000 rows.

This returns EXPLAIN:
[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hm, no thanks - but good luck

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` unless you really need the empty rows.
2. Try to reformulate because `JOIN ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... )` optimizes poorly.
3. Please do not use the same alias (`s`) for two different tables; it confuses the reader.
4. Add the composite index `INDEX(rocnik_id, soutez_id)` to `souteze`.
5. `LEFT JOIN ... JOIN ...` -- Please add parentheses to show whether the `JOIN` should be before doing the `LEFT JOIN` or after:

either

```
FROM ...
LEFT JOIN ( ... JOIN ... )
```

or

```
FROM ( ... LEFT JOIN ... )
JOIN ...
```

It *may* make a big difference in how the Optimizer performs the query, which *may* change the speed.

There may be more suggestions; work through those and ask again (if it is still "too slow").

Comment: Agree the derived tables are slow on mysql if you need to do that replace them with indexed temp tables its more work up front but at least some improvements can be made.